# Where can I find a list of Actionscript Error numbers and their descriptions?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm searching Adobe's documentation and cannot find it.  Specifically, I'm looking for SecurityError #'s and descriptions for the SecurityError class documented here.
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/SecurityError.html#SecurityError%28%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can find an error list within adobe site : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/runtimeErrors.html

and if you want to learn more on security into the flash player here a bunch of links too:
http://www.adobe.com.gt/devnet/flashplayer/security.html

Answer (score 0):

This is another great resource : http://www.actionscripterrors.com/